# Is it possible to create a map of all imports from a react project?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, developer-tools

as above, im curious if there is a way to produce a flow chart or something similar that shows what the structure of imports is from a meteor/react project. it would speed up my development time considerably.

id like something like:

app.js

---mycomponent1 from mycomponent1.js

------mycomponent2 from my component2.js

-------anothercomponent from anothercompoent.js

---yetanotherone from yetanotherone.js

for the entire tree of imports in the project.

something similar to a tree command but that breaks down the flow of what imports what and where.

Comment: have you already ruled out `grep -r import * | grep -v ^node_modules` ? what's missing from that?

Comment: im only looking for the components and i want it from the top down ie if the App.js file is the first thing loaded i would like to have all the imports it loads beneath there with all the imports that each of those files import etc. yea there is probably a grep command that will do what i want but i am not that much of a grep expert to write it and also i was hopeing for somethng more like tree, ie semi graphical if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor has built-in bundle visualizer.

You can run it by `meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer` or `npm run visualize` from your project root.

Also if you mostly interested about your npm modules there is build in npm command `npm ls` which prints out your npm dependency tree.

And of course as it mentioned in other answer there are tons on npm of packages that do similar tasks depending on your needs. For example you can try these [keywords:npm packages tree](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords%3Anpm%20packages%20tree) on npmjs search.

Answer (score 1):

What about this tool:

https://github.com/pahen/madge

> Madge is a developer tool for generating a visual graph of your module
> dependencies, finding circular dependencies, and give you other useful
> info. Joel Kemp's awesome dependency-tree is used for extracting the
> dependency tree.

- Works for JavaScript (AMD, CommonJS, and ES6 modules)
- Also works for CSS preprocessors (Sass, Stylus, and Less)
- NPM installed dependencies are excluded by default (can be enabled)
- All core Node.js modules (assert, path, fs, etc) are excluded
- Will traverse child dependencies automatically